# How can we disable right click + copy + print option (Command + p) on Google Document viewer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdfviewer, google-document-viewer

Requirement:
Need to display the PDF within the application where all the links should be clickable in most of the browsers or at least in Google Chrome, Safari, and Mozilla browsers and disable i)right click, ii) copy and iii) print option (Command + p), in the pdf viewer.

I have worked with the pdf.js library, however, all the links are not clickable. So, I have moved to Google Document viewer here I'm able to access all the links but I'm not sure how to disable the i)right click, ii) copy and iii) print option (Command + p).

As we use the iframe for integrating the Google Document viewer we won't able to control the events on the iframe.

Can anyone suggest me how to disable them from the Google Document Viewer.

(or)

It would be great if you can suggest other libraries were the above requirement is fulfilled.

Backend: Ruby on Rails
Front-end: Rails views

PDFs are stored in AWS.

Thank you!